# Silverlight for Embedded Issues

Tags: silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2005

We are working on WinCE 6.0 application development using Silverlight for Embedded. We are facing some issues with displaying Japanese characters in Device/Emulator.

I have tried the following things to show up the japanese font in Silverlight for embedded application

1.Made the OS with Japanese locale including MS Mincoo and MS gothic fonts and its showing japanese fonts in the Device/Emulator.

Even i am using MessageBox API displayes the japanese word properly

2.In the Page.XAML,i have included FontFamily="Windows/Fonts/MS Minchoo.ttf" to refer the fonts from fonts folder of the Device/Emulator using Windows CE6.0

But Nothing helped and still we are able to see only Square in the place of Japanese characters

Plz help us on this

Answer (score 0):

You must add font to your application.
As far as I know you can't use path like in your example.
[Here is](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/silverlight-3-custom-fonts) good tutorial how to do that.